# Receiver has no segue with identifier, though the segue is actually declared

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uistoryboardsegue

I'm working in a new Swift project, where I'm trying the simple task of executing a `segue` whenever a button is pressed. However, whenever I try to trigger the segue, the following error pops up:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Receiver (<Ma2Mi.LandingViewController: 0x7f99c65122b0>) has no segue with identifier 'showLogin''
```

Relatively simple, except for that there's actually a segue named `showLogin`:

[image]

(the top view controller is of type `LandingViewController`.)

This is how the segue is invoked:

```
loginButton.addAction {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showLogin", sender: nil)
}
```

How is it possible that such a simple task is failing? Perhaps a bug, or something I overlooked?

Thanks.

Comment: How was the instance of `LandingViewController` created?

Comment: @Paulw11 It's all storyboards. `LandingViewController` is the root viewController of this storyboards `UINavigationController`

Comment: Maybe you ctrl dragged from a UI element instead of the view controller instance in storyboard?

Comment: @AndréSlotta I already tried to remake the connection\

Comment: Maybe whitespace in the segue's name? If not this does not make any sense. :)

Comment: What was the answer? I have same issue after rewriting single controller from objc to swift.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the required `init()` function on the ViewController triggering the segue? I had the same issue until I removed it.